# C++: ostream infinite recursion

Tags: c++, stack-overflow, infinite-loop

I am somehow causing infinite recursion (and an eventual stack overflow) to occur inside this destructor:

```
MyMatrix::~MyMatrix() {
    if (this != NULL) {
        cout << "Destructor called for " << this->matrix << ":" << endl << *this << endl;
        /*for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }*/
        delete[] *matrix;
        delete[] matrix;
    }
}
```

If I uncomment the for() loops and remove the end of the initial cout, the function works fine. Therefore, I think that it is caused by the overloaded << operator:

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, MyMatrix a)
{
    if (&a != NULL) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.m; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a.n; j++) {
                output << a.matrix[i][j] << " ";
            }
            output << endl;
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

EDIT:
here is the constructor

```
MyMatrix::MyMatrix(int i_m, int i_n) {
    m = i_m;
    n = i_n;
    if (n < 1 || m < 1)
        throw string("Dimensions cannot be negative");
    matrix = new float*[m];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
       matrix[i] = new float[n];
       for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
           matrix[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post all the code.

Comment: Your `<<` takes the matrix by value. Your destructor calls `<<`, passing it a copy of the matrix. Then that copy needs to be destroyed, which calls the destructor, which calls `<<` and passes it a copy of the matrix, which then needs to be destroyed, which calls the destructor... I think you can see where this is going.

Comment: As @T.C. says, you should be calling by const-reference in the `<<` operator, but also, `this != NULL` and `&a != NULL` can never be true. You should remove them.

Comment: By the way, it's not possible for `this` or `&a` to be a null pointer.

Comment: Good odds that reading this question and answer will help stave off your next bug: [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your declaration of `operator<<`:

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, MyMatrix a);
```

You are passing `a` by value. This causes a temporary copy to be made of the passed `Matrix`, and that copy is destructed when `operator<<` exits.  When you call `operator<<` inside the `Matrix` destructor, you cause a recursive loop.

You should avoid passing function arguments by value whenever possible.  Avoid making unnecessary copies, this slows down your program, as it generates extra code (in this case, a copy constructor and a destructor).

Change your definition of `operator<<` to what it should have been from the start:

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, const MyMatrix &a);
```

A side note: from the code you showed, it seems that you have a `Matrix` containing a `Matrix*`. This is a recursive structure.  I doubt this is really necessary for a matrix.